# NSLayoutConstraint Error: making full subview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, autolayout

I'm making full-frame subview, ( subview's frame = superview's bound )

I made expansion like following

> ```
> [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
>                            constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[subview]-0-|"
>                            options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing
>                            metrics:nil
>                            views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(subview)]];
> [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
>                       constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[subview]-0-|"
>                       options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing
>                       metrics:nil
>                       views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(subview)]];
> ```

But run time error occus, shown the following error.

> ```
> "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1001bb700 h=--& v=--& H:[IUView:0x10015dcc0(960)]>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1001911d0 H:|-(0)-[IUBGView:0x1001783f0]   (Names: '|':IUView:0x10015dcc0 )>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1001910e0 H:[IUBGView:0x1001783f0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':IUView:0x10015dcc0 )>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10017bbf0 H:|-(0)-[NSImageView:0x100160050]   (Names: '|':IUBGView:0x1001783f0 )>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10015d7f0 H:[NSImageView:0x100160050]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':IUBGView:0x1001783f0 )>",
> "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1001a6a80 h=--& v=--& H:[NSImageView:0x100160050(0)]>"
> ```
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>
> Set the NSUserDefault NSConstraintBasedLayoutVisualizeMutuallyExclusiveConstraints to YES to have -[NSWindow visualizeConstraints:] automatically called when this happens.  And/or, break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.

Can you explain what I missed?

Comment: Searching for **"Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint"** on StackOverflow brings up more than 40 similar questions.... have you considered explaining in your question what you've tried so far and why all these don't apply do your case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you're not turning of the 'translatesAutoresizingMaskInotConstraints' feature of the views you've created by hand.

```
someView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

If you don't set that to NO then iOS converts the springs-and-struts (e.g. auto resizing mask) settings to constraints. Those constraints are conflicting with the ones you're making with the visual format language.

Anytime you see the class 'NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint' in the constaints error output then you can be sure you haven't turned off translates.

Good practice is that on every view you create programmatically, you also turn of translates.